# T tap with valve for pex?

Tags: plumbing, water, refrigerator, pex, filter

This picture is of a 1/4 inch PEX line from a reverse osmosis filter. This section is right before a remineralization cartridge. The water before that cartridge is fairly close to being distilled water. I was looking for any product that would allow me to create a t-tap with a valve so I could get distilled water whenever I want and also just easily turn the valve to have the reverse osmosis filter send water to my refrigerator instead.

When I repeatedly disconnect the 1/4" pex line from the cartridge and reconnect it, after a while the seal becomes ruined I found and I figured a t-tap would fix that issue. After looking online for quite a while I am unable to find something that would work.

[image]

Comment: You need a T the tubing size and a plumbing shop will be the right place to look. Asking us to do the shopping is off topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disconnecting and reconnecting those lines will stress the connections and cause them to fail.
It should be simple enough to tap into that 1/4" line using a tee connector as you suggest and then adding a 1/4 inch shutoff valve on the tapline. Following is a link to some inexpensive components but you can probably find them at your local hardware store as well.
[https://www.amazon.com/PureSec-Connect-Fitting-Assortment-Package/dp/B07D629S7W/ref=sr_1_1?dchild=1&gclid=CjwKCAiAhbeCBhBcEiwAkv2cYxp0g2lpGx0N-YKN4TircqwGvjwjL7gY2ceOIzEXMkbJnn8we298EBoC6uAQAvD_BwE&hvadid=384443217506&hvdev=c&hvlocphy=9028825&hvnetw=g&hvqmt=e&hvrand=11177684254370804919&hvtargid=kwd-825352349189&hydadcr=8432_9886307&keywords=1%2F4+inch+t+valve&qid=1615744105&sr=8-1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07D629S7W)

Comment: Thank you so much! This will work for me

Comment: Glad to help. I appreciate the thanks but if you're accepting my answer as the solution a check mark works best.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for a surgical tubing tee.

Something like this:

https://www.coleparmer.ca/i/masterflex-fitting-nylon-tee-female-luer-x-female-luer-25-pk/4550256?PubID=UZ&persist=true&ip=no&gclid=CjwKCAiAhbeCBhBcEiwAkv2cYyR10gGLs8shUTmN7__05dgSvBZswaghQuZ373pNw8u1hZ-B7PRkPxoCqqsQAvD_BwE